# Creating multipoints from points and setting incrementing M value in spatialite

Tags: spatialite, multipart, m-values

I have a layer of points, which I want to group into multipoints grouping by some column. This part is easy:

```
SELECT name_pre, CastToMulti(GUnion(geometry)) AS geometry
FROM sp_survey
GROUP BY name_pre;
```

But the trick is that I'd like to assign to each part of multipoint incrementing m value (0, 1, 2 etc.) based on the "depth" column in sp_survey table, ordered from lowest (0) to highest (n) for each multipoint feature.

Is it possible in spatialite?